# How to get the values of a particular column in excel sheet and make as an array and pass that array as input values in golang?

Tags: arrays, excel, go, excelize

I have a column in excel sheet with random numbers generated from 1 to 1 million.

I would like to read this particular column and store in an array in golang.

Later, i would like to pass this array as my request to my load balancer which will read the values in my column and do the load balancing accordingly.

I am using "github.com/360EntSecGroupSkylar/excelize" for creating an excel file

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I assume that all the other things such as creating, reading, etc. are out of the scope of this question and you have a struct `file` that has the current excel file.
In this case, you can try following:

```
func GetCol(f *excelize.File, sheet string, col rune) ([]string, error) {
    colIndex := int(col) - 'A'
    cols, err := f.GetCols(sheet)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if colIndex >= len(cols) {
        return nil, errors.New("column index out of bound")
    }
    return cols[colIndex], nil
}
```

And use this as following:

```
cols, _ := GetCol(f, "Sheet1", 'B')

for _, col := range cols {
    fmt.Println(col)
}
```

Make sure to use capital column index. You can modify the function to take index directly. Also, make sure to handle errors your way.